# Expressions pour montrer du mépris

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Je viens d’apprendre cette expression en anglais et puis sa traduction en français : “je ne te pisserais pas dessus même si t’étais en feu” et je la trouve vraiment drôle. Pensez-vous que ce serait normal d’utiliser cela et à quel point est-elle forte ?

Quels sont les meilleures expressions pour décrire un mépris sérieux/une haine forte pour quelqu’un ?

Comment: Ce site reprend 16 expressions liées au mépris, en pour chacune quelques exemples : https://www.languefrancaise.net/Synonyme/1066

Answer (score 1):

Il y a une expression vulgaire en français qui reste dans le même champ sémantique "urétique": *pisser à la raie de quelqu'un* (*la raie* étant ici à comprendre comme la raie qui sépare les deux fesses..). Cela exprime un profond mépris pour quelqu'un.

> je leur pisse à la raie !

Answer (score 1):

Les avis sont partagés sur cette question ... ce que l'un trouve extrême, l'autre trouvera banal. Dans la question le sens (propre ou figuré) n'a pas été spécifié, ni le registre linguistique

À mon avis la manifestation du dégout exprime mieux le mépris

**Passif**

> Ils me dégoutent ... Ils sont dégoutants ... Ils font gerber (vomir) ...

**Actif**

> - Je leur chie dessus
> - [ou l'expression de Greg] je leur pisse à la raie

Comment: « Les avis sont partagé sur cette question ...» oui ET non, c'est une question de code social, de volonté de choquer les uns ou d'accointance, de connivence pour d'autres.… — En effet le mépris conduit à écarter la personne méprisée de son chemin sans rentrer dans son jeu/JE, et donc à utiliser de langage le plus neutre possible : le silence (il ne vaut même pas une réponse/définition/explication …) ; essayez de rester silencieux, calme, si possible équanime face à cette personne méprisable, pas plus de vingt secondes après votre mutisme aura atteint sa cible.

Comment: Merci mais je crois qu'on est dans un forum de Français (pour les anglos je crois ...) donc merci encore mais votre commentaire ne semble pas contribuer objectivement à la réponse que nous souhaitons adresser à cette question "Expression la plus adéquate pour exprimer le mépris"

Comment: Le silence est universel et inclus dans toutes les langues et en retour les inclus, y compris celui de la musique : il n'y a plus de notes, plus de mots, et pourtant/alors quelque chose se transmet. Ma réponse relate une expérience forte qui renvoie à l'oralité, elle indique une réaction de la personne méprisable et potentiellement dangereuse déstabilisée par le fait que je ne suis pas entré dans son jeu/JE manipulateur, elle peut être mise en scène dans toutes les langues. Pour l'écriture vos propositions sont valables et pas interchangeables, elles doivent tenir compte des codes du contexte.

Comment: ‘“French Language” a été animé et modéré par des Français souvent hexagonaux (https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile), et utilise l'anglais international pour faciliter les échanges avec les débutants de tout pays.

Comment: Je suis avec toi, à l'oral je te suis, et comme tu dis, l'oral se transcrit aussi.

Answer (score 0):

Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression auparavant. Il y a un mélange un peu étrange de haine/mépris (laisser mourir quelqu'un) et de dégoût (au point que l'on ne lui pisserait même pas dessus).

J'aurais tendance à la décomposer en deux partie :

- le sens de la haine et du mépris, quelque chose de proche (et déjà entendu) serait :

> Tu pourrais crever devant moi, je ne lèverais pas le petit doigt.

- Sur le côté dégout, je pencherait pour quelque chose (de ma composition) comme :

> Je ne te pisserait même pas dessus tellement tu me dégoute.